# Trying to find right event handler to use to load data only on first load with mapbox gl js

Tags: javascript, datatables, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a mapbox map using mapbox gl js of golf course with a [datatables](https://datatables.net/) below it.   If I move the map, the data in datatables is updated. As I zoom in and out datatables is updated.

The problem I have is on the first load, the there is no data in datatables but it shows golf courses on the map.  I need to use `map.once()` but it is not working as expected.  If I use `map.once('click'...)` it works but I need an event to run once loaded.  I tried `render`, `styledata`, `load`, `data` but they don't work. Any ideas?

```
map.on('load', () => { 
   map.addSource(id, source);

   map.addLayer(id, source);

   map.once('click', 'golf_courses', (e) => {
       console.log('event triggered');
   });

   
});
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, you probably want a separate map.on() event handler **outisde** your map.on('load'). Something like `map.on('sourcedata', ({isSourceLoaded, sourceId}) => { isSourceLoaded && sourceId == "golf_courses" && console.log("loaded golf courses") })`